# Facebook image issue. Could it be cache?

Tags: facebook, image, caching

Our website was recently redesigned and since then I have been unable to get the correct image to appear when I choose link.

For instance:

If I post this link:
http://www.horrormovienews.net/article1184.html
It does not show the image of Ethan Hawke as one of the choices for me to post along with this story. I have asked a few other people (co-workers) and some friends who live around the USA, PA, NC, etc. and they can not get that pic as a choice either. One person who lives in MA can see it when he posts a link.
(This happens to every news story in our network of sites since the theme was changed on the sites)

Another bizarre thing is it WILL show the image for this story:
http://www.horrormovienews.net/article1160.html
but not the one at the top of this post.

I have even used the Facebook lint tool about a week ago to try to refresh the cache.

I have tried to many different things to try to fix thing. I changed the image path, the size of the images, etc. Nothing seems to work.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing it? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify og:image tag.  See your results here: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.horrormovienews.net%2Farticle1184.html

Fix up those warnings and then you should be able to share the link much more consistent.